# Qual forma de calcular tempo de Vídeo pelo método getTime()

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, pessoal!

No *Javascript* existe *método* denominado `getTime();` como também o `getDuration();` que nos dá a duração de um vídeo em questão se agregado ao `<object/>` e `<embed/>`.

Pois é, a minha dúvida:

Como capturar do Início ao Fim de um vídeo pelo *método* `getTime();`?

E como comparar se parou, e mostrar uma mensagem notificando que terminou o vídeo?

## Código

```js
var video = document.embeds[0];

var max = video.getDuration();

var seg = video.getTime();   

var con = document.getElementById('txt');

function Tempo()
{     
seg = video.getTime().toFixed(); 

con.textContent = seg;
}     
if ( seg == con ) { clearInterval(id) || alert(video.getDuration().toFixed()) }

var id = setInterval("Tempo()", 1000);
```

```html
<embed src="http://cache28.vuclip.com/53/65/5365756905f3dbd79909b3cce52649a3/ba63207/NiceGuys_5365_w_3.3gp"/>

<hr>

<span id='txt'></span>
```

Visto o que tenho feito até agora. Só falta comparar se chegou ou não no limite da saída `<span id='txt'></span>` e logo em seguida *mostre* o `alert();`.

Comment: Por favor aprenda a usar a marcação de maneira correta. Grato

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta, devido a ao ter visto que você queria mais do que foi dito na pergunta, faça um teste por favor, qualquer duvida me comunique.

Comment: Boa noite Diego, tinham erros no código, mas consegui corrigir hoje, assim eu atualizei a resposta agora, se o código falhar pode me avisar. Até mais

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag object é pra trabalhar com plugins, provavelmente cada plugin usa um método diferente, a questão que vou citar é, ao invés de `<embed>` use a tag `<video>` que é mais correta para isto e serão suportadas por todos navegadores modernos sem necessidade de plugins, ou seja sem plugins os navegadores só irão precisar dos [CODECs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec), geralmente a maioria dos navegadores usam os [CODECs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) do sistema operacional e/ou tem [CODECs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) próprios.

A tag `<video>` tem suporte para vários funções e parâmetros independente do [CODEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) (o mesmo vale para áudios, mas no caso usamos a tag `<audio>`).

Em um exemplo assim:

```
<video id="videoID" width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="http://cache28.vuclip.com/53/65/5365756905f3dbd79909b3cce52649a3/ba63207/NiceGuys_5365_w_3.3gp" type="video/3gp" type='video/3gpp; codecs="mp4v.20.8, samr"'>
</video>

<script>
(function () {
    var obj = document.getElementById("videoID");
    console.log(obj.currentTime, obj.duration, obj.ended);
})();
</script>
```

- `.currentTime` retorna ou define a posição atual em segundos
- `.duration` retorna a duração do video
- `.ended` retorna true se o video tiver terminado, caso contrário retorna `false`

Além destes você também pode usar os eventos como:

- `ended`
- [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate)

O código ficaria assim:

```
<video id="videoID" width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="video.3gp" type="video/3gp" type='video/3gpp; codecs="mp4v.20.8, samr"'>
</video>

<hr>

<span id='txt'></span>

<script>
function parseTime(seconds)
{
    seconds = !seconds ? 0 : seconds;

    var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    var mins = Math.floor((seconds - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var secs = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
    var formated = [];

    if (hours > 0) {
        formated.push(hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours);
    }

    formated.push(mins < 10 ? "0" + String(mins) : mins);
    formated.push(secs < 10 ? "0" + String(secs) : secs);

    return formated.join(":");
}

(function() {
    var video    = document.getElementById("videoID");
    var boxTexto = document.getElementById("txt");
    var isEnded  = false;

    video.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        isEnded = true;

        boxTexto.textContent = "Quer uma pipoquinha a mais, compre novos ingressos.";
    }, true);

    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
        if (!isEnded) {
            boxTexto.textContent = parseTime(this.currentTime) + " / " + parseTime(this.duration);
        }
    }, true);
})();
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acrescentado o que @Guilherme Nascimento disse sobre:

Plug-ins

A finalidade de um plug-in, é estender a funcionalidade do navegador HTML.

HTML Auxiliares (Plug-ins)

Aplicativos auxiliares são programas de computador que ampliam a funcionalidade padrão de um navegador web.

Aplicativos auxiliares também são chamados plug-ins.

Exemplos de plug-ins conhecidos são mini-aplicativos Java, Flash.

Os plug-ins podem ser adicionados a páginas da web com a tag `<object/>` ou a tag `<embed/>`.

Os plug-ins podem ser usados ​​para muitas finalidades além de Vídeo e Áudio.

Assim também como:

O elemento `<object/>` é suportado por todos os navegadores.

O elemento  define um objeto incorporado dentro de um documento HTML.

Ele é usado para incorporar plug-ins (como mini-aplicativos Java, leitores de PDF, Flash Players, entre outros) em páginas da web.

O elemento `<embed/>` é suportado em todos os principais navegadores.

O elemento `<embed/>` também define um objeto incorporado dentro de um documento HTML.

Os navegadores da Web têm apoiado o elemento `<embed/>` por um longo tempo. No entanto, não tem sido uma parte da especificação HTML antes HTML5. O elemento irá validar em uma página HTML5, mas não em uma página HTML 4.

Tudo bem, chega de tais explicações e vamos ao que interessa, o código resposta da pergunta. Enfim após trabalho árduo cheguei ao fim, posto para quem quiser fazer o mesmo fique sabendo com é, ha detalhe utilizei um Firefox com MPlayer Plug-in nele.

```js
var video = document.embeds[0];

function tempo()
{     
var seg = video.getDuration() - video.getTime();

document.getElementById('txt').textContent = seg.toFixed();

if ((seg - 1) >= 0) { document.getElement('txt').textContent = 'Player Ativo...'; } else { document.getElement('txt').textContent = 'Player Inativo.'; clearInterval(zero); } 
}

var zero = setInterval(tempo, 3500);
```

```html
<embed src="http://cache28.vuclip.com/53/65/5365756905f3dbd79909b3cce52649a3/ba63207/NiceGuys_5365_w_3.3gp"/>

<hr>

<span id='txt'></span>
```

> Na verdade o que realmente queria com esse código era o seguinte: após finalizar o vídeo voltar sua thumbnail/screenshot
>
> Mas para isso precisava capturar o tempo decorrido e logo mostrar a mensagem, e esta mensagem na verdade era somente um indicativo se deu certo ou não pela contagem regressiva da duração do vídeo.

Agora cabe a vocês soltarem a criatividade.

Comment: Por que usou a tag `document.all.txt` ao invés de `document.getElementById('txt')`? Sabe que document.all é apenas para IE?